# Confidence intervals for percentage change

Tags: confidence-interval

I am working with COVID-19 case data, and I derive the week-on-week growth which is basically the % change in weekly cases. I am looking to bound this data with a confidence interval,but I am not sure what method to use.

Comment: A confidence interval for which fixed parameter? And based on what assumptions on the time series?

Comment: A more appropriate question might be how to get a confidence inteval for a new number of cases given a past number of cases.  Percent change has a lot of statistical problems.  One of them is that if the number of cases doubled (100% increase) you'd need a 50% decrease to return to the original level.  See https://fharrell.com/post/percent.